# Calculating the variability of angles between multiple vectors

Tags: statistics, vectors

I'm working with multiple 3D vectors (all with the same magnitude) that describe the direction some object as it moves over several trials. The starting vectors of each trial are supposed to be the same, but due to sensitivity of measurement and human error they are all slightly different. I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the variability of the **angle** between start positions.

My idea was to take the mean of the vectors, then find the angle between each vector and the mean vector. Perhaps those angles could be used as the "deviation from mean" when calculating standard deviation? I'm just not sure that makes sense, or maybe there's a better way to think about this entirely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a sensible idea. Just one small comment: if the vectors are about the same magnitude, this is fine. If not, you might want to normalize them before you calculate the average direction.

Comment: I should specify that. Yes, the vectors are all the same magnitude. Thank you for the response!